# Is using ear buds harmful?

Tags: side-effects, hearing, instruments

In which way it is harmful to ear?
What other measures can be taken to clean the ear ?

Answer (score 1):

The use of ear buds in it of itself is probably not harmful.

The physical shape and the effort used to place the ear buds can be potential areas of abuse.
However, what has the most real-world potential of being harmful to your ear is most likely what comes out of those ear buds. 
E.g. ear buds are being used to listen to very loud music/sounds.

> With extended exposure, noises that reach a decibel level of 85 can
>   cause permanent damage to the hair cells in the inner ear, leading to
>   hearing loss. Many common sounds may be louder than you think…
>
> - A typical conversation occurs at 60 dB – not loud enough to cause damage.
> - A bulldozer that is idling (note that this is idling, not actively bulldozing) is loud enough at 85 dB that it can cause permanent damage
>     after only 1 work day (8 hours).
> - When listening to a personal music system with stock earphones at a maximum volume, the sound generated can reach a level of over 100 dBA,
>     loud enough to begin causing permanent damage after just 15 minutes
>     per day!
> - A clap of thunder from a nearby storm (120 dB) or a gunshot (140-190 dB, depending on weapon), can both cause immediate damage.

Long term use of ear buds can also cause sensitivity in and around your ear, causing some pain when touched or upon pressure. The size and shape of the ear buds would help to mitigate this, but not everyone's ears are the same exact size and shape.

Comment: This post has the makings of a good answer, but here on Health, we [*strongly encourage*](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/q/1) using references. They are the only way in which we can tell if information is reliable or not. If you are struggling to find good sources, check out, [What are reliable sources?](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/q/112) If you want to learn more about our site's stance on answers without references, check out, [Should answers without references be immediately deleted?](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/q/283) (Can you at least cite where you got your info?)

Comment: I don't know if this was in the question when you answered it, but it says 'What other measures can be taken to clean the ear ?'. It's obviously talking about ear buds for cleaning the ears, not earphones.